# Weird EOFError with python and paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.X.X.X',username='user',password='password')

stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("get system status")
type(stdin)
stdout.readlines()
```

Quite simple as I thought, but running throws a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/workspace/FortiNet/src/runCommand.py", line 8, in <module>
    ssh.connect('10.X.X.X',username='user',password='password')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 325, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 492, in start_client
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1726, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 386, in read_message
    header = self.read_all(self.__block_size_in, check_rekey=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 251, in read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

I'm a bit confused here and maybe I'm blind, but I can't find the problem.

thanks

Obviously: connecting per "normal" ssh and running this command works perfectly fine :-)

I changed to python 2.7 (the default on Mac) and removed the 3.5 installation completely.
I now get a different error (still EOFError though):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/workspace/FortiNet/src/runCommand.py", line 8, in <module>
    ssh.connect('10.X.X.X,username='user',password='password')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 325, in connect
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 492, in start_client
EOFError
```

As said before, I can perfectly fine connect to the box with "normal" ssh.
I also tested python's connectivity with:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(0.5)

try:
        s.connect(('10.2.2.254',22)) 
except Exception, e:
        print 'connection failed'
else:
    print "success"

s.close()
```

and it worked (i.e. printed "success"), but for whatever reason, paramiko seems to be unable to connect.
I tried my code step by step in a python shell to see when the error occurs and it happens right after

```
ssh.connect('10.X.X.X',username='user',password='password')
```

Comment: Can you try to enable logging to see exactly at what stage the connection attempt fails, e.g. by doing `import logging; logging.basicConfig(); logging.getLogger('paramiko.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have faced same error while writing a script to access fortigate remotly. i can see that you are trying on a forigate too.

I have changed the config on the fortigate under "config system global" and it worked (i don't know which change actually did it , it needs some trial and error to know)

```
config system global
     - set admin-server-cert "Fortinet_Factory"
     - set admin-sport 2222
     - set admin-ssh-grace-time 20
     - set admin-ssh-v1 enable
     - set auth-cert "Fortinet_Factory"
     - set dh-params 1024
     - set fgd-alert-subscription advisory latest-threat
     - set gui-theme red
     - set gui-wireless-opensecurity enable
     - set hostname "FortiGate-VM64"
     - set ssh-cbc-cipher disable
     - set ssh-hmac-md5 disable
     - set strong-crypto disable
     - set timezone 04
end
```

please let me know if you did know which one was essential.

Comment: set dh-parms 1024 did it. Kinda weird, as according to the Fortinet Doc, this command is for SSL related stuff only, not ssh. I'll update the ticket at github/paramiko and also ask Fortinet for details.

Comment: To clarify for others: It's a fortinet bug. The fortunate is excepting dh-group1 during negotiation without actually supporting it. since 5.4 you can set dh-params=1024. When you run 5.2.5 or 5.2.6 you need to exclude dh-params in the paramiko module. there are no problems with 5.2.4 and below. A fix is expected in 5.2.7 and 5.4.1 in Q2/16

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping out. I did as you suggested and got:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x7fe51d0L
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_1.16.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-a3WzN
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client a3WzN)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:[u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:[u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'arcfour', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:[u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'arcfour', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr'] client mac:[u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:[u'none', u'zlib'] server compress:[u'none', u'zlib'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-md5
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
```